# Detecting LINQ Inserts Before submitChanges and using BulkInsert Instead

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, bulkinsert

I've got a bunch of code that is setup to add 10k to 20k inserts to a LINQ DB in addition to a few updates/deletes.  All of these changes are committed through a db.SubmitChanges() call.  The problem is it's **too slow :(**  The performance has been thoroughly tested in this great post on StackOverflow:

[Very slow insert process using Linq to Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750999/very-slow-insert-process-using-linq-to-sql)

The issue is that I do not want to rewrite all of the code that prepares my DB object.  I've attempted to psuedo code what I'd like to do below.

**Disclaimer: This is not real code!  It will not compile.... not even close :)**

OLD WAY:

```
SchedDB.Data.SchedulerDBDataContext db = new SchedDB.Data.SchedulerDBDataContext();
//Do a bunch of stuff to populate "db"
db.SubmitChanges()
```

NEW WAY:

```
SchedDB.Data.SchedulerDBDataContext db = new SchedDB.Data.SchedulerDBDataContext();
//Do a bunch of stuff to populate "db"
//NEW: Detect all of the inserts in the "db" object.  Remove those inserts and generate code to insert them with a batch dataadapter.  For example:
//
//DataTable dtProducts = new DataTable()
//dtProducts.Columns.Add(ProductID) //yada yada all of the columns here
//
//DataTable dtCustomers = new DataTable()
//dtCustomers.Columns.Add(CustomerID) //yada yada all of the columns here


//foreach (insertItem in db.Inserts) //this is pseudo code, I need help here
//{
//   if (insertItem.destinationTable == "Products")
//   {
//      DataRow dr = dtProducts.NewRow();
//      dr["ProductID"] = insertItem.ProductID; //This line of code probably isn't even close to being right... I can't imagine the "insertItem" holding all of the columns no matter what the destinationTable is
//   }
//   if (insertItem.destinationTable == "Customers")
//   {
//       //similar code, all customer columns, yada yada
//   }
//   IMPORTANT: remove the item from the LINQ db so it doesn't insert it anymore
//
// Make a table adapter for each datatable
// Set the .BatchSize parameter
//Commit each table adapter.
// db.SubmitChanges()  //If there are any updates or deletes they are still in here and still need to happen.
```

If there are any errors in the mass updates then it would be nice to know that so I can roll back the LINQ db and potentially run some other code to clear the dataapapters inserts. (I can handle this, all of my inserts have an extra column that is an int that is unique to the batch insert.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found the answer to my question.  A sweet class you can download from here:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LinqEntityDataReader

This class is perfect for me, I can just pass a collection of "Customer" objects generated by LINQ to SQLBulkCopy!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing all of this, why not just insert db.SubmitChanges(); calls after each individual item, or after blocks of X items? That's not ideal, either, but better than submitting massive changes all at once, and potentially very easy to change in the code.

Feed the DataContext moderately sized updates, and it doesn't actually do a bad job of getting them done for you. Then move on to more productive things.

Comment: There are a couple of reasons I do not want to go this path:

1. The code for populating the LINQ db object is spread out over multiple areas and is too spread out to start modifying everywhere.  I need to be able to operate on the fully populated db object.

2. I still think the performance is bad relative to the post I referenced about.  I want to take advantage of that post as the inserts are extremely fast there.  db.SubmitChanges() is a separate insert for each and every row.

Comment: Well, if you are unable to do significant changes to the code, there's likewise likely very little you can do.